# microsoft report landscape issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have generated reports using microsoft report viewers in c#.

For making the report print in landscape view i used the code:

```
reportViewer1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
```

This code i placed over `Form Load` Event as well as `reportviewer load` event as Follows :

```
private void BillPDF_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dsBillPDF.totalBill' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.totalBillTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsBillPDF.totalBill,AllBill.fromDate);
            reportViewer1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }

        private void reportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            reportViewer1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        }
```

Unfortunately, this code is not working.

Is usage of `reportViewer1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;` is wrong? or i have written it in wrong position.

Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At first glance your code looks fine. I found I needed to refresh the report every time I changed its orientation. From experience, I had the same problem you did with Landscaping using ReportViewer. You'll need to change the width and height settings so that the width is larger than the height.

### Select the report properties

The white portion of this screenshot is the bottom of my report. Now just **right click** and select "**Report Properties...**" below the report footer (anywhere in the blank space).

[image: Right Click]

### Report Properties

Here you can also set your orientation to Landscape (but you did it by code so that's fine). Make sure the paper size format (Letter in our case) is supported by your Printer... *Some printers will not handle "Custom" formats* for example.

If the width is still smaller than the height, adjust it manually and you should be able to fix your issue.

Margins are also important. You might want to play around with the margins whenever you print and / or export to PDF. ReportViewer has caused me some issues whenever I was doing this.

[image: Report Properties]

If all of this fails, try stretching your report like this and repeat the property procedures:
[image: Report ruler set to 27cm]

The report ruler on my .rdlc is set to 27 centimeters or so.

### My code snipet (VB.NET)

```
    sReportDataSource.Name = "rptBillDataset" 'Dataset name associated to the report
    sReportDataSource.Value = ds.dsBillDetail 'Dataset value
    rv.rvRdlc.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(sReportDataSource)
    rv.rvRdlc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
    rv.rvRdlc.RefreshReport()
    rv.Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings ps = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings();

ps.Landscape = true;

this.reportViewer1.SetPageSettings(ps);

Work for me in VS 2010 Pro

Answer (score 0):

If you do it like this you get the current page setting not the default ones

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings ps = reportViewer1.GetPageSettings();
ps.Landscape = true;
reportViewer1.SetPageSettings(ps);
```